# Laravel pagination $paginator->currentPage always is 1

Tags: laravel, pagination

I made a custom pagination with laravel.
I use ajax to update results.
When I click on 1 2 3 ... etc, the results are updated correctly.
But, I don't know why current page is always 1.

print_r($paginator->currentPage()) is 1 everytime

Comment: You need to upload some code so we can help. Also are you aware of Laravel's default pagination functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my ajax request:
let formData = new FormData;
                formData.append("page", page);

```
            $.ajax({
                data: formData,
                url: "{{ route('get-reviews') }}",
                type: "post",
                headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,

                success: function (data) {
                    $("#results-div").html(data);
                }
```

Page is get correctly in this request.

```
li class="{{ ($paginator->currentPage() == 1) ? ' disabled' : '' }}">
            @if($paginator->currentPage() != 1)
                <a class="page-button" data-page="{{ $paginator->currentPage()-1 }}"><<</a>
            @else
                <span aria-hidden="true" style="cursor: not-allowed"><<</span>
            @endif
        </li>
        @endfor
```

Above is a portion from pagination.blade.php

Current page is always 1